# Android - detecting user has left the network wireless range and turning off WiFi

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, wifimanager

I've been doing some research into this feature for a potential app. I want to give the user the option to turn off WiFi (automatically) when they are getting no signal from a specific network, or perhaps when no data has been transmitted over the connected network for a specific amount of time.

I've seen a promising method in the WiFiManager object, called getScanResults, which returns some information regarding each network, one of which is the signal strength or RSSI, so I would assume I could get the signal strength for the network from this, and manage the currently connected network to detect when it's below a certain level.

However, I've done a small amount of research into this feature, and some applications seem to do it based on triangulation using GPS/mobile data. Is this because it's more accurate?

Is my original idea feasible, using the WiFi manager (or any other Android libraries), can you control WiFi usage based on the signal strength of a network (i.e. its gone below 0), or the network activity (0 for 10 minutes, etc.)

Thanks!

Comment: It is feasible however it will need to be a service that will run in the background, and all it would do is try to connect to a network via wifi every 5-10 mins? This was an idea I had too but did not follow up on :) yeah GPS is annoying and wastes alot of battery.

Comment: Okay, so I'd just get it to attempt to reconnect after a period of time. What if it is already connected, what would happen if you attempted a reconnect, could you just get it to pass the check and not attempt to reconnect at this point?

Comment: you can make it so that while(!connected) you could search and try to connect :) A request can be made to the wifi manager to see if status is connected.

Answer (score 1):

A service can be used to achieve the objectives stated above. The service can have a timer when not connected, a request can be made to the manager on the service which would get all the information from a broadcast receiver.

- [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)
- [Broadcast Receiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)
- [This page can be used tofigure out how to find if wifi is connected, I know it is to do withWifiP2p however it is very similar!](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html)